# Why Bootstrap style lost on Chrome's print preview

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, printing, window.open

i develop an angularjs web-app and i need to print a page.
So: from the main web-page --> onclick i 'window.open()' a new tab with only the DOM elements that i need for the print --> on ctrl+p the chrome's prine preview opens and the bootstrap seems not to work , the two header columns (colmd-6) , take full width and they are the one under the other instead of side by side.

### The main webpage:

[image]

### I use window.open:

When the user clicks on the print icon (top right), i use the `window.open(..printfloorplan.html)` to isolate the floorplan image , so far so good:

**the js snippet**:

```
        var newWin = window.open("/assets/modules/print/templates/printfloorplan.html");    
        var canvasImage = $scope.img_create(imgsrc,'floorplan','floorplan');
        //add canvas image to the DOM
        newWin.onload = function() {
            //here i update the DOM elements by:
           //newWin.document.getElementById('name).innerHtmle = val;
        };
```

**The printfloorplan.html**(i use media=print on styles):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="screen,print" HREF="../../../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="all" HREF="../../../css/print.css">
    <title>print floorplan</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="background-color: #d3d3d3;">
    <!--/*1st row `header`*/-->
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:10px;"> 
        <div class="col-md-6 a1"> 
            <table> 
                <tr> 
                    <td> 
                        <img id="logoframe" src="/assets/modules/login/img/start/logo_frame.png"> 
                        </td>
                    <td class="space" ><table>
                        <tr><td id="onomalabel"></td><td class="space" id="onomaevent"> <!-- onoma--></td></tr>
                        <tr><td id="datelabel"></td><td class="space" id="datestart"><!-- date--></td></tr>
                        <tr><td id="halllabel"></td><td class="space" id="hallname"><!-- aithousa--></td></tr>
                        </table></td>    
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right a2" style="padding-top:22px"> 
            <img id="poweredbyLogo" src="/assets/modules/login/img/powered_by_logo_print.png" >
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--/*2nd row floorplan image*/-->
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center" id="floorplanimg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*so the new window opens as i want it, with all the style*
[image]

### Here cames the problem , on Ctrl+p:

*It seems as the bootstrap doesnot recognised here, although i used media=print*

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[image]